# Post and retrieve JSON's request with CakePHP

Tags: jquery, json, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a problem posting and retrieving JSON data with CakePHP.

In the view file, I'm posting data using code that looks more-less like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: '/invoices/insertItem/',
    data: {'description': "this is description", 'invoice_id': 17},
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response, status) {
        alert ("Success");
    },
    error: function(response, status) {
        alert('Error! response=' + response + " status=" + status);
    }
});
```

Related controller looks like this:

```
public function insertItem() {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
$this->beforeRender();
$this->autoRender=false;
Configure::write('debug', 1);  // just for testing purpose, in other way it's 0

$data = $this->request->input ( 'json_decode', true) ;
//$data = $this->set('_serialize', array('data')); // tried with this
//$data = $this->request; // tried with this also
pr($data); // it's empty! why?!

    $invoice_id = json_decode($data['pass'][0]);
    $description = json_decode($data['pass'][1]);

    $this->InvoiceItem->create();
    $this->InvoiceItem->set('invoice_id', $invoice_id );
    $this->InvoiceItem->set('description', $description );
    $this->InvoiceItem->save();
exit;
}
```

Whatever I tried, collected data in controller is always empty. Can you help me what I'm doing wrong in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the json string as follows

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: '/invoices/insertItem/',
    data: '{"description": "this is description", "invoice_id": 17}',
    //  --^-^-----------^-------------------------^----------^-----^--
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response, status) {
        alert ("Success");
    },
    error: function(response, status) {
        alert('Error! response=' + response + " status=" + status);
    }
});
```